# How to Click on item of recycler view using robotium

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

i have **Robotium 5.4** but i don't know how to click on an item in **Recycler view** in android.

Comment: Check (Why do text and button clicks get wrong?) here https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Questions-&-Answers

Comment: @Tasos but i didnt got my answer there

Comment: Then im not sure -- check this seminar on Robotium  -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGsO9YEvQEU  -- got to time 44:22, tehy are talking about clicks

Comment: Thanks @Tasos but u are misunderstanding i am handy with the basic concepts of robotium but in robotium 5.4 i am able to call the object of Recycler view.

Comment: @Bridge you have found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me worked method clickInRecyclerView(int itemIndex).

From source code:

> /**    * Clicks the specified item index and returns an ArrayList of the TextView objects that
>   * the item index is displaying. Will use the first RecyclerView it finds.
>   *
>   * @param itemIndex the item index to click
>   * @return an {@code ArrayList} of the {@linkTextView} objects located in the item index      */
>
> public ArrayList clickInRecyclerView(int itemIndex) {

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your existing `Robotium` version to 5.5.3 - the latest release. It has the feature to scroll `RecyclerView`. Visit [here](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Changelog)